# Question about Lebesgue outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I recently started studying Lebesgue measure, and I have a doubt :

Let $A\subset \Bbb{R}^n $ . The Lebesgue outer measure is defined as $ m^*(A) = \inf \{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}l (I_k) : A \subseteq \cup_{k=1}^{\infty}I_k\}. $

Now, it is also true that if we have $A\subset \Bbb{R}^2 $, the Lebesgue outer measure of $A$ is the product of the lenght of the $x_1$ interval multiplied by the lenght of $x_2$ interval.

My problem is that I dont see exactly what is the relationship between the definition of of Lebesgue outer measure and the example of $A\subset \Bbb{R}^2 $.
I would like some clarification about this. Thanks.

For example, let { $ (x,0) :  1 \leq x \leq 2$ } = A.
I understand that the Lebesgue outer measure of this is zero. But I dont see how to apply the definition.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ example?

Comment: @IrvingRabin Edited.

Comment: You can cover $A$ with just one rectangle of width $\epsilon>0$ and length $1$. Letting $\epsilon \to 0$ shows $A$ has measure 0.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Yes, I know. But my question is this : If  we follow the definition of Lebesgue outer measure, and 0 is the value, then 0 has to be the infimum of a certain set. I dont understand how to construct that set.

Comment: @AndrewZhang The infimum of that set has to be equal with the volume of the interval. I dont see why is the case. I hope to be clear (English is not my main languague)

Comment: I’m not sure what your hesitation is towards my approach. Maybe you can elaborate?

Comment: @AndrewZhang The infimum of that set is the smallest volume in that set? And in this case, 0? That is my question. Sorry if I didnt explain it very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to grasp what the general definition of the outer measure is.
$$
m^*(A) = \inf\left\{\sum_1^\infty l(I_k):A \subseteq \cup_1^\infty I_k\right\}
$$
This says that the outer measure is the infimum of many *overestimations* for volumes of coverings of $A$, which indicates why we call it an *outer measure*, it determines the volumes by measuring from the outside.

In your example $A = \{(x,0)\mid 1 \leq x \leq 2\} = [1,2]$, i.e it is a *line segment in the plane*. You can certainly cover it with a rectangle defined by say $[0,5]\times[-3,3]$, but is this a covering with the smallest possible volume? As Andrew Zhang writes, if you take a rectangle with width $\varepsilon>0$ and cover the line segment with it, you can shrink the width down to $0$ completely covering the line segment, but what is the area of such a rectangle?